# Object not found while doing funnel() in the `meta` package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am aware that my question is similar to [a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340928/knit-error-object-not-found). However, I believe that my case is different. I am experiencing `Object not found` error while knitting my markdown. However, I believe that the dataset is loaded correctly in the R Markdown environment.

Below is the code chunk I wrote in my R Markdown:

```
library(meta)
library(metafor)
library(readxl)

data.binary <- read_xlsx(path="data/metabin.xlsx")
View(data.binary)

ma.binary <- metabin(
                    event.e = ee,
                    n.e = ne,
                    event.c = ec,
                    n.c = nc,
                    studlab = paste(Author),
                    data = data.binary,
                    comb.fixed = TRUE,
                    comb.random = TRUE,
                    method.tau = "DL",
                    hakn = FALSE,
                    prediction = TRUE,
                    sm = "RR"
                    )
forest(ma.binary)

funnel(ma.binary, xlab = "Risk Ratio")
```

The above chunk returns this error:

```
Error in funnel(ma.binary, xlab = "Risk Ratio") : object 'ma.binary' not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> funnel
```

I have tried clearing my environment with `rm(list = ls())` but the problem persists. Furthermore, when I delete the `funnel(ma.binary, xlab = "Risk Ratio")` part, the chunk runs perfectly fine, hence I believe that the dataset is loaded correctly in the R Markdown.

Is something wrong with my code chunk?

Comment: have you tried explicit name spacing, metafor::funnel?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Yes, I've tried explicit name spacing, but the problem persists.

Comment: and I'm guessing you also tried restarting your R session?