# When knitting a markdown file I have an error "object not found"

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I write the following code in markdown

```
summary(supermarket_sales_Sheet1)
```

and hit the knit button ,I got the following message:-

```
Error in summary(supermarket_sales_Sheet1) : 
  object 'supermarket_sales_Sheet1' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> summary
Execution halted
```

What's the problem please?

Comment: The most likely reason is that `supermarket_sales_Sheet1` is an object which exists only in your global environment. When you knit the Rmd is executed in a fresh and clean R session. Hence, only objects which are created in the Rmd could be used. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42341558/12993861

Comment: Yes, create supermarket_sales_Sheet1 in a chunk above the one where you summarize it