# R code works in script but not R markdown

Tags: r-markdown, rscript

#The code below works fine in my scripts but not in R markdown.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
age <- kaggle_2020_Survey %>%
  transmute(Q1 = as.factor(Q1)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Q1)) %>% 
  count(Q1) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)*100)


ggplot(age, aes(x = Q1, y = n)) + geom_col(fill = "darkblue", alpha =.7) +
geom_text (aes(x = Q1, y = n, label = paste0(round(perc,1), "%"),hjust = -.3), size = 3) 
+
coord_flip() + labs(title = "Age of participants", x = "Percent", y = "Number", 
subtitle = "Highest age group: 22-24") +
theme_classic()
```

#This is the error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fw8X.png)

Comment: Welcome at SO! Better give you error description as text too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the object is in your environment but you forgot to include something like

```
library(tidyverse)
kaggle_2020_Survey <- read_csv("kaggle_2020_Survey.csv")
```

where you load in the data. When you knit a rmarkdown file it starts a new session each time so if the data isn't called in before you start doing stuff then it will throw that error

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340928/knit-error-object-not-found) answer goes into other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this. It solved the issue.