# line missing in the line chart when knitting an rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

the code runs fine in the rmarkdown but the line is missing when i knit.

the code :

```
cyclistic_v2$day_of_week <- ordered(cyclistic_v2$day_of_week, levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))

cyclistic_v2 %>%
  group_by(member_casual, day_of_week) %>%
  summarize(number_of_rides = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day_of_week, y = number_of_rides, group = member_casual, color = member_casual)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = " Number of rides per day of week for each customer type")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help us to help you would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. Also could you clarify what you mean by "the line is missing when I knit"? Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: Hi stefan ,no i don't get an error i just get a line chart without line when i knit

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I reproduced your plot using the `Case Study - Cyclistic Bike share (2018-2019)` dataset.

Sample code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)   


cyclistic_v2 $day_of_week= factor(cyclistic_v2 $day_of_week, levels= c("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))

 cyclistic_v2 %>%
      group_by(member_casual, day_of_week) %>%
      summarize(number_of_rides = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% # 'drop' removes the group attribute and by default, it removes the last group
      ggplot(aes(x = day_of_week, y = number_of_rides, group = member_casual, color = member_casual)) +
      geom_line() +
        labs(title = " Number of rides per day of week for each customer type", x="Number of rides", y="Day of the week", color = "Rider status")+
      theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

[202004-divvy-tripdata.zip](https://www.rpubs.com/IronStark007/782256)

Comment: Yes it works but when i knit the rmarkdown the line is missing

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340928/knit-error-object-not-found