# Why will my code run directly but I can't knit the rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to produce a simple scatterplot with Human Development Index on the horizontal axis and the average Infant Mortality Rate on the vertical axis. However, i got the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 144-153 [unnamed-chunk-4] (pset1.Rmd)
Error:
! object 'hdi_health' not found
Backtrace:
 1. base::plot(...)
Execution halted
```

I tried using this to create the scatterplot:

```r
plot(hdi_health$avg_hdi, hdi_health$avg_infant_mortality,
     ylab = "Infant Mortality Rate",
     xlab = "Average Human Development Index",
     main = "Infant Mortality Rate based on Average Human Development Index")

model <- lm(hdi_health$avg_infant_mortality ~ hdi_health$avg_hdi,
            data = hdi_health)

summary(model)
```

which worked. However, I am unable to knit the project. I can only knit if I delete all the code.

Comment: Unclear how you load `hdi_health`. The rmd will knit in a fresh session so it won't have access to your objects unless the script loads them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knit error. Object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340928/knit-error-object-not-found)